# Why map does not force strictness whereas zipWith does?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, strictness

There are two strict versions of zipWith function:

1) Really strict, elements of lists l1 and l2 get evaluated so their thunks do not eat all stack space (Don Stewart code)

```
zipWith' f l1 l2 = [ f e1 e2 | (e1, e2) <- zipWith k l1 l2 ]
            where
                k x y = x `seq` y `seq` (x,y)
```

2) Not really strict, attempt to force evaluation by other way.

```
zipWith'' f l1 l2 = [ f e1 e2 | (e1, e2) <- zip (map (\x -> x `seq` x) l1) (map (\x -> x `seq` x) l2) ]
```

The question is: why the equivalent code from the 2nd example using *map* does not make the function also strict?

Comment: The `zipWith'` function will force any element thunks in l1 and l2 as it processes the elements, but the `f e1 e2` thunk is not forced.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a common mistake to use

```
x `seq` x
```

Which is exactly equivalent to

```
x
```

An excellent explanation is available in [Neil Mitchell's post on Bad Strictness](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/05/bad-strictness.html).

Comment: Interesting but it does not correspond why the following versions **are not equivalent**:         zipWith''' f l1 l2 = [ f e1 e2 | (e1, e2) <- zip (sLst l1) (sLst l2) ]
            where
                sLst [] = []
                sLst (x:xs) = x `seq` x : sLst xs
        and                zipWith''' f l1 l2 = [ f e1 e2 | (e1, e2) <- zip (sLst l1) (sLst l2) ]
            where
                sLst [] = []
                sLst (x:xs) = x : sLst xs

Comment: Recursive construction of list with *x `seq` x : sLst xs* makes it strict whereas "equivalent" *x : sLst xs* does not ...

Comment: Those are not equivalent. The first version you wrote is `seq x (x : sLst xs)`. Mind the associativity.

Comment: Forget it, my mistake due to functions precedence. The former expression without parens did meant x `seq` (x : sLst xs).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of tautological `map`, one can use this function to force the list:

```
evl []     = []
evl (x:xs) = x `seq` (x:evl xs)
-- Cannot figure out how to do this with fold.
```

Then the strict `zipWith` is

```
zipWith''' f xs ys = zipWith f (evl xs) (evl ys)
```

Comment: This will not work for infinite lists, while Don's version will.

Comment: Some explanation for beginners like me why n.m.'s solution won't work for infinite lists ?

Comment: @jaspervdj: It seems to work with infinite lists too (it forces the elements, not the spine).